# I am having problems with the Wordpress function get_template_part()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Good afternoon 
I am looking for help with the following function 'get_template_part()'

below I have provided the code I am using, but it doesnt seem to connect to the reusable code, please help.

the code below is located in the following directory: template-parts.php>page-loop.php:

```
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(  ); ?>
        <h1 class="text-center text-primary"><?php the_title( ); ?> </h1>

        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail()):
        the_post_thumbnail('blog', array('class'=> 'featured-image'));

        endif;
         ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

and here is the page using the function:

```
<?php
/*
*Template Name: Page with sidebars
*/

 get_header( ); ?>

<main class="container page section with-sidebar" >
<div class="page-content">
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/page', 'loop' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(  ); ?>

</main>

<?php get_footer( ); ?>
```

I am not seeing where the error is, I am following a course and I think I have the same code, but the page content has disappeared.
please help.
Thank you.

Comment: _“page content has disappeared”_ - you mean, completely, and you only get a “white page”? Then you likely have a 500 Internal Server Error, so the next step now would be to go and check the error log, to find out what caused it. (Also, enable WP debug mode, if you have not done that already.)

Comment: No , not the page entirely, but the resusable code that has been moved.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the missing semi-colon on your if statement, and add an else to see if it gets triggered:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1 class="text-center text-primary"><?php the_title( ); ?> </h1>

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()):

        the_post_thumbnail('blog', array('class'=> 'featured-image'));

    endif; ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <article>
        <h5><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'mytheme' ); ?></h5>
    </article>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If the closing statement is not on the same line, it is recommended to use a semi-colon.

Comment: Yes, I have just watched the video again and just like you say i have a missing semi colon after endif....
let me put this in and I will get you back.

Comment: No , no luck, it appears that the function is not pulling the content into the page.
I am going to look at your code and mine again.

Comment: I think the error is somewhere in the function. but not sure where.

Comment: Check my updated code. Always add an else statement to rule out no content being fetched. And then break your template down piece by piece, returning just the_title(), then adding stuff back in.

Comment: The page has a sidebar with is working fine, its just the content of the page...
it was working fine before i removed it and used the : get_template_part(), I understand what you are saying, before I created the reusable code and the existing code was placed in the page, it was working fine, but it stopped as soon as I replaced it for the get_template_part() function, I am just trying to see whats not working for that function.

Comment: the additional code hasnt made any difference, it hasnt appeared.

Comment: Remove all code from page-loop and replace with a simple <h1>Loop Test</h1> - does that get returned? If not, your folder structure may be incorrect.

Comment: SOLVED!!!
I found out the I had named the folder/ directory wrong, i had called it template-parts.php and that it should be Template-parts. Silly error. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!
silly error
I inadvertenly named the folder : template-parts.php, once i renamed it just 'template-parts' it worked.

code is soo critical lol.

many thanks for all your help.